# Upgrading orchard from 1.8.2 to 1.10.2. but the build in vsts is failing in the 'Drop' step

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, upgrade, orchardcms-1.10

Upgrading orchard from 1.8.2 to 1.10.2. but the build in vsts is failing in the 'Drop' step with the following error : "Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\s\ReleaseManagement\Zipped" .

Does this mean that any of the settings or config files are overwritten?

Guess some config information regarding the generation of ReleaseManagement.zip is missing.

Answer (score 0):

During the upgrade the package.proj file and the MSbuild folder got deleted .Because of this the required releasemanagement zip file and other files didnt get generated. After including the deleted files back the build passed successfully.